# MPI Segmentation Fault On Multiple Nodes Only

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, mpi

So I am currently building the basis of a control program to run on multiple raspberry Pis that will use all of the available cores on each pi. When I test my code on one of the nodes using all of the cores it works fine, but using multiple nodes gives me a segmentation fault.

I looked at all the similar questions asked in the past, but they all had issues that would have broken my code on only one node too.

The full code:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h> 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        FILE *input;
        char batLine[86];   //may need to be made larger if bat commands get longer
        char sentbatch[86];
        int currentTask;
        int numTasks, rank, rc, i;
        MPI_Status stat;
        bool exitFlag = false;

        //mpi stuff
        MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);  //initilize mpi enviroment
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numTasks);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
        //printf("Number of tasks: %d \n", numTasks);
        //printf ("MPI task %d has started...\n", rank);
        if(argc != 2)
        {
            printf("Usage: batallocation *.bat");
            exit(1); //exit with 1 indicates a failure
        }
        //contains file name: argv[1]
        input = fopen(argv[1],"r");

        currentTask = 0;
        if (rank ==0)
        {
            while(1)
            {
                if(exitFlag)
                    break; //allows to break out of while and for when no more lines exist
                char command[89] = "./";
                for(i=0; i < 16; i++) //will need to be 16 for full testing
                {

                    //fgets needs to be character count of longest line + 2 or it fails
                    if(fgets(batLine,86,input) != NULL)
                    {
                        printf("preview:%s\n",batLine);
                        if(i==0)
                        {
                            strcat(command,batLine);
                            printf("rank0 gets: %s\n", command);
                            //system(command);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //MPI_Send(buffer,count,type,dest,tag,comm)
                            MPI_Send(batLine,85,MPI_CHAR,i,i,MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
                            printf("sent rank%d: %s\n",i,batLine);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        exitFlag = true; //flag to break out of while loop
                        break;
                    }


                }   
                //need to recieve data from other nodes here
                //put the data together in proper order
                //and only after that can the next sets be sent out

            }
        }
        else
        {
            char command[89] = "./";
            //MPI_Recv(buffer,count,type,source,tag,comm,status)
            MPI_Recv(sentbatch,86,MPI_CHAR,0,rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);
            //using rank as flag makes it so only the wanted rank gets sent the data
            strcat(command,sentbatch); //adds needed ./ before batch data
            printf("rank=%d recieved data:%s",rank,sentbatch);
            //system(command); //should run batch line
        }
        fclose(input);
        MPI_Finalize();
        return(0);
}
```

The contents of the file being passed:

```
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-006.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-006.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-008.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-008.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-010.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-010.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-013.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-013.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-015.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-015.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-018.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-018.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-022.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-022.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-023.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-023.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-024.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-024.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-025.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-025.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-028.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-028.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-029.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-029.nor f
```

You will notice I am not yet doing a few things that will be done in the final version and they are in comments to make trouble shooting easier. Mostly because the LAMOST code is not fast, and I do not want to be waiting for it to complete.

The command prompt that works and the output for it:

```
 $mpiexec -N 4 --host 10.0.0.3 -oversubscribe batTest2 shortpass2.bat
preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.nor f

rank0 gets: ./LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.nor f

sent rank1: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.nor f

sent rank2: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.nor f

sent rank3: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.nor f

rank=1 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.nor f
rank=3 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.nor f
rank=2 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.nor f
```

Shortpass2 is just the same file but with only the first 4 lines. My code should theoretically work with all 16 lines but I will test it with a full file after fixing the current issue.

Running on multiple nodes command and output:

```
$mpiexec -N 4 --host 10.0.0.3,10.0.0.4,10.0.0.5,10.0.0.6 -oversubscribe batTest2 shortpass.bat

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.nor f

rank0 gets: ./LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.nor f

sent rank1: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.nor f

rank=1 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.nor f
sent rank2: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.nor f

rank=2 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.nor f
sent rank3: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-006.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-006.nor f

rank=3 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.nor f
sent rank4: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-006.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-006.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-008.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-008.nor f

rank=4 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-006.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-006.nor f
[node2:27622] *** Process received signal ***
[node2:27622] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[node2:27622] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[node2:27622] Failing at address: (nil)
[node2:27622] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
corrupted double-linked list
Aborted
```

Sometimes it will successfully get to rank 5 before aborting completely, and there will be multiple instances of the same error message. Additionally, Open MPI was installed with multiple thread support so that isn't the issue. This is my first time using MPI but this is not the first part of the whole project and I have done a ton of research into MPI to even get this far with it.

I know it isn't caused by my arrays since then it would be breaking on node1 as well. All of the pis are identical so it wouldn't make sense for the arrays to be causing the segmentation faults. (Although I admit I have had that issue come up several times working on the different parts of this project because I am more used to how Java and C# handle arrays)

**Edit:** I checked to see if I could run it across 4 cores from one of the other nodes and that works fine and produces the same output as it did on node1. So that confirms it not being an array issue that only happens on the other nodes.
Also added a line that was missing in the code for the preview print out.

**Edit2:** Per Gilles suggestion: The code works with running 16 tasks all on one node as well. Here is the output from that:

```
$ mpiexec -N 16 --host 10.0.0.3 -oversubscribe batTest4 shortpass.bat
preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.nor f

rank0 gets: ./LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.nor f

sent rank1: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.nor f

sent rank2: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.nor f
preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.nor f

sent rank3: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-006.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-006.nor f

sent rank4: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-006.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-006.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-008.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-008.nor f

sent rank5: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-008.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-008.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-010.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-010.nor f

sent rank6: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-010.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-010.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-013.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-013.nor f

sent rank7: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-013.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-013.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-015.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-015.nor f

sent rank8: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-015.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-015.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-018.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-018.nor f

sent rank9: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-018.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-018.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-022.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-022.nor f

sent rank10: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-022.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-022.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-023.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-023.nor f

sent rank11: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-023.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-023.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-024.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-024.nor f

sent rank12: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-024.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-024.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-025.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-025.nor f

sent rank13: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-025.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-025.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-028.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-028.nor f

sent rank14: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-028.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-028.nor f

preview:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-029.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-029.nor f

sent rank15: LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-029.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-029.nor f

rank=3 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.nor f
rank=5 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-008.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-008.nor f
rank=6 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-010.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-010.nor f
rank=7 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-013.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-013.nor f
rank=11 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-023.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-023.nor f
rank=12 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-024.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-024.nor f
rank=9 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-018.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-018.nor f
rank=2 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.nor f
rank=4 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-006.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-006.nor f
rank=8 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-015.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-015.nor f
rank=10 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-022.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-022.nor f
rank=15 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-029.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-029.nor f
rank=1 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.nor f
rank=13 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-025.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-025.nor f
rank=14 recieved data:LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-028.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-028.nor f
```

Comment: Ranks 4 and above receive but are never sent anything. Try running 16 tasks on a single node and see what happens (you will need to `mpirun --oversubscribe ...`

Comment: How are you getting output such as `rank=4 received data ...` when you run with `mpiexec -N 4 ...`? Ranks in that case range from 0 to 3.

Comment: it seems `mpiexec -N 4 --oversubscribe ...` means 4 MPI tasks per node (at least with Open MPI `v2.0.x`). Anyway, the `for() MPI_Send()` loop never sends to rank 4 and above (and there is no such thing as `preview` in the code) so the output clearly does not match the code you posted.

Comment: Gilles is correct. Using "-N" and not -n allows it to make 4 tasks per node. As for running 16 tasks on one node is that even allowed? Each pi only has 4 cores. For the preview, I must have forgotten to add it on my notepad. It should be before " "if (rank ==0)". It was a test to ensure fgets was working properly.

Comment: Gilles, I tried running it with 16 tasks on one node as you suggested in your previous comments and that worked just fine. I will edit the output into my original question in case it will be of any use

Comment: Unless you can point me to the line where a message is sent to task `4`, you need to update the code you posted.

Comment: It is fixed now. The for loop just still had the old 4. 16 is the number when running it on all nodes. (Which is what I was running. I just didn't notice the code had the smaller 4 on here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more attempts of searching for similar issues, I finally found the answer of what is wrong in the code. It just took searching for the error message in so many different possible inputs.

The lines:

```
input = fopen(argv[1],"1");
fclose(input);
```

needed to be within rank 0 only. Meaning the correct code to get it to run on multiple nodes is:

```
//has file open and closed moved to hopefully work on multiple nodes
//now only occurs for task0 which is on node1
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h> 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        FILE *input;
        char batLine[86];   //may need to be made larger if bat commands get longer
        char sentbatch[86];
        int currentTask;
        int numTasks, rank, rc, i;
        MPI_Status stat;
        bool exitFlag = false;

        //mpi stuff
        MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);  //initilize mpi enviroment
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numTasks);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
        //printf("Number of tasks: %d \n", numTasks);
        //printf ("MPI task %d has started...\n", rank);
        if(argc != 2)
        {
            printf("Usage: batallocation *.bat");
            exit(1); //exit with 1 indicates a failure
        }
        if (rank ==0)
        {
            //contains file name: argv[1]
            input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
            while(1)
            {
                if(exitFlag)
                    break; //allows to break out of while and for when no more lines exist
                char command[89] = "./";
                for(i=0; i < 16; i++) //will need to be 16 for full testing
                {

                    //fgets needs to be character count of longest line + 2 or it fails
                    if(fgets(batLine,86,input) != NULL)
                    {
                        if(i==0)
                        {
                            strcat(command,batLine);
                            printf("rank0 gets: %s\n", command);
                            //system(command);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //MPI_Send(buffer,count,type,dest,tag,comm)
                            MPI_Send(batLine,85,MPI_CHAR,i,i,MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
                            printf("sent rank%d: %s\n",i,batLine);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        exitFlag = true; //flag to break out of while loop
                        break;
                    }


                }   
                //need to recieve data from other nodes here
                //put the data together in proper order
                //and only after that can the next sets be sent out

            }
            fclose(input);
        }
        else
        {
            char command[89] = "./";
            //MPI_Recv(buffer,count,type,source,tag,comm,status)
            MPI_Recv(sentbatch,86,MPI_CHAR,0,rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);
            //using rank as flag makes it so only the wanted rank gets sent the data
            strcat(command,sentbatch); //adds needed ./ before batch data
            printf("rank=%d recieved data:%s",rank,sentbatch);
            //system(command); //should run batch line
        }

        MPI_Finalize();
        return(0);
}
```

I don't know how acceptable it is to answer your own question, but I wanted to ensure that if anyone has the same issue they know how to fix it. I know I hate when I find a similar question only to see that the asker edited in that they fixed the issue without explaining how they fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that is **the** problem, but it definitely is **a** problem:

You are reading and then sending 85 characters from `batLine` here:

```
char batLine[86];

//fgets needs to be character count of longest line + 2 or it fails
if(fgets(batLine,86,input) != NULL)
{
    // ...
    MPI_Send(batLine,85,MPI_CHAR,i,i,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    // ...
}
```

Given that `batLine[]` is 86 elements, and that `LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.nor f\n` is 85 characters long, the string you are sending doesn't include the `\0` terminator which is in the 86-th array element.

On the receiving side you have:

```
char sentbatch[86];

{
    char command[89] = "./";
    // ...
    MPI_Recv(sentbatch,86,MPI_CHAR,0,rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);
    strcat(command,sentbatch);
    // ...
}
```

`sentbatch` is never initialised, so initially it contains garbage. Since all incoming messages are 85 characters long, the 86-th character is never overwritten and it keeps holding whatever garbage was there initially. Consequently, if that wasn't `\0`, then `strcat()` will continue reading garbage from `sentbatch` past the 85-th character and appending to `command`. Since both `command` and `sentbatch` are on the stack, the read will continue either until it hits a `0x00` somewhere on the stack, at which point writing past the end of `command` will have destroyed other local variables or even the stack frame causing a potential segfault later on, or until it reaches the end of the stack, which will definitely cause a segfault. That it works sometimes and in some ranks is purely by accident.

Either change `MPI_Send` to send 86 characters or explicitly zero the 86-th element of `sentbatch`. Or, even better, use `strncat(command, sentbatch, 85)` to append no more than 85 characters or directly receive into `command` using

```
MPI_Recv(&command[2],86,MPI_CHAR,0,rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);
```

`char command[89] = "./";` pads the remaining 87 elements of `command[]` with `\0`, so no problems with the terminator in this case.

Comment: each line on the file is 84 characters long not counting the new line and carriage return. So a total of 86 characters. I previously forgot the carriage return and when only getting 85 characters the output would skip sending anything to task 1, 3, and so on. Command having a length of 89 then works as it has 3 characters. 2 visible and then the automatic \0.  That being said, I will try changing it to see if it helps.

Comment: Changing the array sizes and the send and receive to include an extra element did not change the output in any way. As for all the files, the length of each line is constant as that file is created by another part of the code. I did not write that part of code and so can not share it here. Regardless, how it creates that file isn't a part of this issue anyway.